# Can I make a html element with 100% height bigger than vh?

Tags: html, css

I'm confused as to what making a html element "height: 100%;" does exactly.

- I've made both html and body 100% height
- I've added a few 100% height sections inside
- The content displays correctly.

But then I looked at the page with Inspect Elements and I noticed that even though the contents displayed are above 100vh, the html, the body and the wrapper are all exactly 100vh.

**Is this normal behaviour?** Should I refrain from changing the height of the html and body element unless I want a site that's strictly 100vh?

Answer (score 0):

height is always relative to its parent.

If you have html's height as 100vh, and then body as height: 100%, then body will also be 100vh, because body's parent is html, and the height is always relative to its parent.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the html's height is 100%, not 100vh, but 100% height seems to be the same as 100vh, and I'm not sure if that is normal behaviour.

Comment: @AlbertoBurrito 100% of the webpage or 100 viewport height are basically the same. They are all relating to the screensize of your window. If you said 1080px by 1920px on a 4k monitor though, you would see that it's not 100% of the viewport.

Comment: Not sure I follow on the last part, from what I understood setting 100% height for te html element is basically the same as setting 100vh for the html element. Are you saying this wouldn't apply on a 4k monitor?

Answer (score 0):

The 100% is covering 100% of the parent. What the % corresponds to is determined by what modifier it is included with. If a height is set to 100% it will scale linearly with vh. If a width is set to 100% it will scale with vw. So yes, it is normal to see 100% height correspond to 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

The `vh` unit means "Viewport Height". Setting the `html` or `body` `height` to `100vh` is essentially redundant since a page will always want to fit within the height of the viewport in the first place.

> Should I refrain from changing the height of the html and body element
>   unless I want a site that's strictly 100vh?

I can't think of any scenario where you'd want to set the `html` or `body` height at all. It is much more common to set the height of elements "within" the body, not the body itself.

Comment: Using Bootstrap, when wanting to center an element horizontally and vertically in a webpage, we need to set `h-100` to the body and the actual element or else it won't budge.

Comment: There are some scenarios where body and height at 100% or 100 vh would be an option though not strictly necessary. But yeah it just didn't really make any sense in the situation I was in atm.